# Why are my Azaleas failing?

Tags: plant-health, azaleas

I bought 5 azaleas from the garden centre about 4 months ago and planted them in my front garden.

3 of them are doing fine (the first two pics show what they are like).

But 2 of them are really small and the leaves are turning brown on the tips.

I planted them all in the same topsoil with ericaceous soil around them and I've been feeding them with the correct plant food etc...

Just not sure what is happening that's causing the smaller two to turn brown like this...

Healthy plants
[image]
[image]

Failing plants :(
[image]
[image]

Comment: They're not actually failing - do the plants get any sun?

Comment: @Bamboo yes, lots of sun. I assumed they're not doing so well due to the difference with the first two. The first two are lush and green and now about twice the size of the second two. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun depends on where you are; In TX is is difficult to grow azaleas in full sun, it requires daily water . However yours look good. Brown tips usually means it got too dry. Azaleas like acid soil like pH 6. Is there possibly a soil pH difference ?

Comment: It has been very dry and hot here for the past couple weeks. (In UK though so relatively balmy compared to Texas, haha). I planted them in the same topsoil with conditioner around them. I’ll feed them more regularly with the acidic plant food. Thanks 

Comment: Do you think it would be worth uprooting them to add more acidic soil around them?

Comment: They look good so  working calcium sulfate or some other acidifier  into the surface soil should be enough. Probably worth getting a soil test to determine if it may be a problem.

Comment: excellent, thanks 

Answer (score 1):

If they get a lot of sun, then the heatwave we had in the UK recently may have caused this - the smaller ones will also have smaller root systems, so they would have felt the impact more, and may have needed a little more watering than the larger ones.

Otherwise, they look very healthy - plenty of new growth showing, so as long as you can't see any pests on the plants, just see how they go. Pretty sure you've been having adequate rain since the heatwave broke up where you are...